# How to .htaccess redirect domain to subdomain while keeping the main domain intact

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dns, subdomain

I want to redirect all urls under my domain

domain.com/urls, www.domain.com/profile/user1.html etc. to subdomain.domain.com/urls and subdomain.domain.com/profile/user1.html etc.

but I dont want to redirect domain.com and www.domain.com to subdomain.domain.com

Is it possible via htaccess?

Edit: I want to redirect just the internal pages and files only. But leaving the main domain.com intact.

More Examples

```
domain.com/page1.html to subdomain.domain.com/page1.html

www.domain.com/members/admin.html to subdomain.domain.com/members/admin.html

www.domain.com to www.domain.com (no redirection here)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/.+
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.(php|htm)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^subdomain.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://subdomain.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

If you want to permanently redirect, change the square brackets to: `[L,R=301]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can first handle the main page by *not* rewriting and redirect everything else with a second rule

```
RewriteRule ^$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^subdomain.domain.com$
RewriteRule ^.+$ http://subdomain.domain.com/$0 [R,L]
```

When everything works as you expect, you can change `R` to `R=301`.

Comment: This worked for the subdomains but the homepage did not load and chrome browser said that there were some sort of infinite loop.

Comment: @user1675934 Strange, I used these rules in my test environment and they worked fine. Anyway, if Jon's answer solved your problem, that's fine and you should accept it.